# Downloading only selected attributes using Overpass turbo

Tags: openstreetmap, query, overpass-api

Does anyone know of a query to download select attributes using Overpass turbo?

I am trying to download very granular road dataset for an entire country, but I only want a few columns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Overpass does not have this feature now. In Overpass Turbo You can export the data in geojson format and then open it in http://geojson.io to remove unwanted columns.

Answer (score 1):

You can download a [country extract](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Planet.osm#Country_and_area_extracts) instead and filter it afterwards for specific data using [osmosis](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmosis) or [osmfilter](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmfilter).

Answer (score 1):

Use [CSV as output format](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Overpass_QL#CSV_output_mode)

```
[timeout:900]
[out:csv(
  // select fields for csv output
  ::id,
  name
)]
;

// query ...
node(1234); out;
```